# RestFul webService and Database Transactions

Tags: php, rest

Lately i'm struggling with Rest architecture :p and i usualy raise a lot of problems with it.
Let's say that i have a resource named "user", and that user can have a list of cars.
Im trying to insert that user and his list of cars in the database at once. I know i have to do this with the POST HTTP verb. But how would i achieve this? Should i send only one URL with the user identification and the list of cars somehow encoded or should i use the "user" resource to insert the user, and then for each car, call a POST URL in a resource named "car"?

The second approach has a problem. This process must be implemented with a Database Transaction. If something goes wrong when inserting a car, i want the user to not be regitered in the database.

I know restFul architectures must be stateless, so how can i implement such a transaction using the database functionalities? I know i can implement myself some kind of transaction, but i wanted it to be more automaticaly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do it depending on the languages you're using in the front and backend and how you plan to send this data. I would solve the problem like so, assuming you're using PHP and MySQL:

1. Get the data ready, so something like `user=123&cars[]=1&cars[]=2&cars[]=3` (I'm using the var `cars[]` as this will send an array to PHP and you can achieve this by naming your input fields as `cars[]`)
2. Post this to your backend
3. Your backend will then process the user and add them to the database if they're not there.
4. I would then have a table that illustrated the relationship between the user and the cars, something along the lines of:

   CREATE TABLE box_to_category (
     user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
     car_id int(11) NOT NULL
   );
5. In this table I'd clear all cars associated with that user and then add the new cars as POSTed to the backend (the `user_id` will be associated to a `user` in a `users` table and the `car_id` will be associated to a `car` in the `cars` table)

It's a simple set up.

Comment: This approach i know how to do it :p. It's a valid answer of course. I wanted to know the other approach, where you would send each car in a URL, so you'd have to implement some kind of database transaction system.

But, since you showed this approach, let me ask you something..With this approach, let's imagine that our user was some kind of arab sheik, and he has a lot of cars. If this was the case, you could end up to build a URL too large to be sent right? Since this is a POST method, the solution would be to increase the POST MAX SIZE in the server? And if it was a GET request?

Comment: And with this approach, isn't possible to send an object encoded? Lets say i wanted to send the cars, and send their id and name. How would you do? An array like carId[]=1&carId[]=2&carName[]&carName[], and match the two arrays by their index? Or is there a way to send the object somehow encoded?

Comment: Yes you would have to increase the max post size and I wouldn't recommend doing it via GET. However, the max post size for PHP is 8MB by default which is a *lot* of text. As for doing it as a encoded object, yep that's fine too, whatever works for you. IMO I'd say it's better to do it in one call that saves 1000s of cars rather than 1 and 1000 calls for the user and then each car.

Comment: Can you please point something that teatch how to encode and send an object?

Comment: JSON is always a good place to start: http://www.json.org/js.html, but again since you **should** do it as a POST, you don't _really_ need to encode anything.